# Arithmetic Evaluation using Stacks and Postfix Notation

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-mta

I'm a C++ newcomer.

For the next project in class, the professor asked us to code a program that calculates a mathematical expression, that we input an infix notation, convert it to postfix and calculates it. I think I have pretty much finished the code, but there are some lines that I'm probably doing wrong and I don't really know what is it. Can you please take a look at it and tell me why am I wrong.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <stack>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

bool operatorCheck(char c)
{
    if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int priority(char c)
{
    if (c == '*' || c == '/')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (c == '+' || c == '-')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

string InfixToPostfix(string expression)
{
    stack<char> operators;

    string postfix;

    for (int i = 0;i< expression.length();i++)
    {
        if (expression[i] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9')
        {
            string temp;
            temp += expression[i];
            int temp2 = i + 1;
            while (true)
            {

                if (expression[temp2] >= '0' && expression[temp2] <= '9')
                {
                    temp += expression[temp2];
                    temp2 += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            postfix= postfix + temp + " ";

        }
        else if (operators.empty())
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if (operatorCheck(expression[i]))
        {
            if (priority(operators.top()) < priority(expression[i]))
            {
                operators.push(expression[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                while (!operators.empty() && priority(operators.top()) < priority(expression[i]))
                {

                    postfix += operators.top();
                    operators.pop();
                }
                operators.push(expression[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (expression[i] == '(')
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if (expression[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!operators.empty() && operators.top() != '(')
            {
                postfix += operators.top();
                operators.pop();
            }
            operators.pop();
        }
    }

    while (!operators.empty())
    {
        postfix += operators.top();
        operators.pop();
    }

    return postfix;
}
//Main program
int main()
{
    string expression;
    stack<int> calc;

    cout << "Welcome to my program!" << endl;
    cout << "This program will help you to calculate arithmetic expression." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter an arithmetic expression (Remember to enter space between numbers and operators):" << endl;
    getline(cin, expression);
    string postfix = InfixToPostfix(expression);
    cout << postfix << endl;

    for (int i = 0;i < postfix.length();i++)
    {
        if (postfix[i] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (postfix[i] >= '0' && postfix[i] <= '9')
        {
            string temp;
            int temp2 = i + 1;
            temp += postfix[i];
            while (true)
            {
                if (postfix[temp2] >= '0' && postfix[temp2] <= '9')
                {
                    temp += expression[temp2];
                    temp2 += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            int n = atoi(temp.c_str());
            calc.push(n);
        }

        else if (postfix[i] == '+')
        {
            int temp1 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int temp2 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int result = temp2 + temp1;
            calc.push(result);
        }

        else if (postfix[i] == '-')
        {
            int temp1 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int temp2 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int result = temp2 - temp1;
            calc.push(result);
        }

        else if (postfix[i] == '*')
        {
            int temp1 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int temp2 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int result = temp2 * temp1;
            calc.push(result);
        }

        else if (postfix[i] == '/')
        {
            int temp1 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int temp2 = calc.top();
            calc.pop();
            int result = temp2 / temp1;
            calc.push(result);
        }
    }
    cout << calc.top() << endl;
}
```

For example, with this expression ( ( 7 + 6 ) * ( 16 - 2 ) ) / 2,

It returns 7 6 +16 6 2 -*2 / ( there is an extra 6) for the postfix. Why is this happened?

Comment: Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have a problem with the `InfixToPostfix` function then we don't need to see the code calculating the result.

Comment: More related to your problem, please learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. That usually helps in finding problems like this. Also please take some time to read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: But praise whatever deities in which you believe. That `std::stack` in use! No wheel reinvention!